# Force-stop MP3 file playback when program complete

Tags: c++, macos

I added the following to my program:

```
system("afplay intro_music.mp3 &>/dev/null &");
```

Audio is playing in background as expected, but when the program exits (whether I use CMD+C or use my "quit game" function that just return 0;, it still continues to play. Even when I close out Visual Studio Code, it still continues lol Any help with this?

FYI - the dev/null was to keep the audio going as the program continues, instead of hanging and finishing playing before proceeding with rest of the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your System to Stop the music in your Code.
The music does not stop, because it is a programm Independent from VScode and your program.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm having trouble getting that to work now. Would I have to use the same system function? If so, what is the syntax like?

Comment: Got it! Used ```system("killall afplay");```